# vectorization of date range function for transformation of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

This is a problem of transforming date range to a numerical values based on the current date.

Input table:

```
   ID   START_DATE  END_DATE    CURRENT_DATE
    1   2010-12-08  2011-03-01  2011-04-01
    2   2010-12-10  2011-01-12  2011-01-02
    3   2010-12-16  2011-03-07  2010-10-10
```

Output table:

```
   ID   START_DATE  END_DATE    CURRENT_DATE    number_of_days
   1    2010-12-08  2011-03-01  2011-04-01      78.148490
   2    2010-12-10  2011-01-12  2011-01-02      23.726149
   3    2010-12-16  2011-03-07  2010-10-10      0.000000
```

where nubmer_of_days is computed based on an exponential decay function, followed by summation of all values for one row.

We can implement a function as follows:

```
def transform(start, end, current):
    value = 0
    if current > end: #current date is later than the end date
        delta = end - start 
        for i in range(delta.days + 1):
            diff = current - (start + td(days = i))
            value += math.exp(- 0.001 * diff.days)
    elif current > start: #current date is between the start and end
        delta = current - start
        for i in range(delta.days + 1):
            diff = current - (start + td(days = i))
            value += math.exp(-0.001 * diff.days)
    else:
        pass
    return value
```

and then apply the below transformation:

```
df['number_of_days'] = df.apply(lambda x: transform(x['START_DATE'], x['END_DATE'], x['CURRENT_DATE']),axis=1)
```

However, this is very slow for a table with millions of rows and huge date range.

Any idea on how to speed up the process by vectorizing the inner for loop in the transformation function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could vectorize using `numpy array` functions to calculate the exponential decay.

```
df = df[df.CURRENT_DATE > df.START_DATE] # just focusing on cases with calculation
```

Get the relevant `delta` depending on `CURRENT_DATE` and `END_DATE`:

```
delta = df[['END_DATE', 'CURRENT_DATE']].min(axis=1).subtract(df.START_DATE).dt.days.add(1)
```

Calculate the `shift` of the `arange()` for exponential decay as `max` of difference between `END_DATE` and `CURRENT_DATE` or `0`:

```
shift = df.CURRENT_DATE.subtract(df.END_DATE).dt.days.clip(lower=0)
```

Produce and process the (adjusted) `arange` objects using `np.exp()` and `np.sum()`:

```
df['number_of_days'] = [np.sum(np.exp(-0.001 * (np.arange(d) + s))) for d, s in zip(delta.values, shift.values)]
```

to get:

```
   START_DATE   END_DATE CURRENT_DATE  number_of_days
ID                                                   
1  2010-12-08 2011-03-01   2011-04-01       78.148490
2  2010-12-10 2011-01-12   2011-01-02       23.726149
```

If you compare performance, you see the efficiency gains from saving on loops:

```
df_test = pd.concat([df for _ in range(100000)])

def transform1(df):
    df = df[df.CURRENT_DATE > df.START_DATE]
    delta = df[['END_DATE', 'CURRENT_DATE']].min(axis=1).subtract(df.START_DATE).dt.days.add(1)
    shift = df.CURRENT_DATE.subtract(df.END_DATE).dt.days.clip(lower=0)
    return [np.sum(np.exp(-0.001 * (np.arange(d) + s))) for d, s in zip(delta.values, shift.values)]

%timeit transform1(df_test)
1 loop, best of 3: 4.99 s per loop

def transform2(df):
    df['end'] = [d.days for d in df.CURRENT_DATE - df.START_DATE]
    df['start'] = (df.end - [max(0, d.days + 1) for d in (df.END_DATE.where(df.CURRENT_DATE > df.END_DATE, df.CURRENT_DATE) - df.START_DATE)])
    df['number_of_days'] = [sum(np.exp(-0.001 * i) for i in np.arange(stop, start, -1)) for start, stop in zip(df.start, df.end)]
    df.drop(['start', 'end'], axis=1, inplace=True)

%timeit transform2(df_test)
1 loop, best of 3: 36.7 s per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the start and end (integers) for each date range.  Then it is relatively easy to vectorize the `number_of_days` calculation.

```
df['end'] = [d.days for d in df.CURRENT_DATE - df.START_DATE]
df['start'] = (
    df.end - [max(0, d.days + 1) 
              for d in (df.END_DATE.where(df.CURRENT_DATE > df.END_DATE, df.CURRENT_DATE) 
                        - df.START_DATE)])

df['number_of_days'] = [sum(np.exp(-0.001 * i) for i in np.arange(stop, start, -1)) 
                        for start, stop in zip(df.start, df.end)]
df.drop(['start', 'end'], axis=1, inplace=True)

>>> df
   ID START_DATE   END_DATE CURRENT_DATE  number_of_days
0   1 2010-12-08 2011-03-01   2011-04-01       78.148490
1   2 2010-12-10 2011-01-12   2011-01-02       23.726149
2   3 2010-12-16 2011-03-07   2010-10-10        0.000000
```

Comment: Thank you! The running time improves a lot.